# Move all Files of same extension to a Folder

Tags: files, automation

I know I can use something like  `mv *zip zip/` but I want to auto-create each folder if not exists and move my all files to them. With the below code I have to hard code everything. Is there any way to automate this. Like First Get all Extensions of files then Create folders if not exists and move files into them according to file types like png to images/png and mp3 to Audio/mp3 or pdf to Documents/pdf.

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec mv "{}" ./Videos \;
```

[image]

**Edit-1**
I have figured someway but I don't want to move .sh files how to delete from an array of a specific element and Group filetypes like png, jpg to images/png, images/jpg and mp3 to Audio/mp3 or pdf to Documents/pdf.

```
array=($(find . -type f | sed 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq ))

for dir in "${array[@]}"; do
        [[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && mkdir "$dir"
        find . -name "*.$dir" -exec mv "{}" ./"$dir" \;
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving files based on file type
You can batch create your directories, move the files, then delete empty directories.

```
ScriptRoot='/some/path'

# Create the Directories
mkdir '${ScriptRoot}/Images'
mkdir '${ScriptRoot}/Music'
mkdir '${ScriptRoot}/Documents'
mkdir '${ScriptRoot}/Videos'

# Move the files (edit to match the targeted extensions...
find '${ScriptRoot}' -name '*.mp3' -or -name '*.flac' -exec mv {} '${ScriptRoot}/Music' \;
find '${ScriptRoot}' -name '*.jpeg' -or -name '*.jpg' -or -name '*.png' -exec mv {} '${ScriptRoot}/Images' \;
# find (... and so and so for Documents and Videos)

# Delete empty directories
find '${ScriptRoot}' -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Moving files based on file extension is way simpler but that is not what was asked.
To achieve what described, this can be modified with a file list generated by find, looped with a while read and several tests on file ext for moving to directories

```
for filename in *; do
  if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then
    ext=${filename#$base.}
    mkdir -p "${ext}"
    mv "$filename" "${ext}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: How to address same file name issue? for example, in a CSV folder, there is a result.csv and we are moving another result.csv. How to prevent overwriting ?

Answer (score 1):

**Use this to organize your files** Thanks to [cmak-fr](https://askubuntu.com/users/77093/cmak-fr)

```
#images
declare -a array=("Images" "Images/png" "Images/jpg")

for dir in "${array[@]}"; do
    [[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && mkdir "$dir"
done

#Music Videos Executable & Fonts
declare -a array1=("Music" "Videos" "Executable" "Fonts")
for dir in "${array1[@]}"; do
    [[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && mkdir "$dir"
done

#Documents
declare -a array2=("Documents" "Documents/xlsx" "Documents/data" "Documents/docx" "Documents/pptx" "Documents/pdf" "Documents/txt" )
for dir in "${array2[@]}"; do
    [[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && mkdir "$dir"
done


#Compressed
declare -a array3=("Compressed" "Compressed/zip" "Compressed/targz")
for dir in "${array3[@]}"; do
    [[ ! -d "$dir" ]] && mkdir "$dir"
done

#Music
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*mp3\|.*flac\)' -exec mv {} Music/  \;

#images
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*jpeg\|.*jpg\|.*JPG\)'   -exec mv {} Images/jpg  \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*png\|.*PNG\)'   -exec mv {} Images/jpg  \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*ai\|.*bmp\|.*ico\|.*svg|.*tiff|.*psd\)' -exec mv {} Images/jpg  \;

#Videos
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*mp4\|.*avi\|.*mkv\|.*mpeg|.*3gp|.*mpg\)' -exec mv {} Images/jpg  \;

#Documents
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*ppt\|.*ppt\|.*pps\|.*odp\)'   -exec mv {} Documents/pptx  \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*ods\|.*xls\|.*xlsx\|.*xlsm\)' -exec mv {} Documents/xlsx  \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*doc\|.*docx\|.*rtf\|.*wpd\)'   -exec mv {} Documents/docx  \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*pdf\|.*epub\)'   -exec mv {} Documents/pdf  \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*csv\|.*db\|.*sql\|.*dat\)'   -exec mv {} Documents/data  \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*txt\)'   -exec mv {} Documents/txt  \;

#Compressed
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*zip\)'   -exec mv {} Compressed/zip  \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*tar.gz\)'   -exec mv {} Compressed/targz  \;
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*7z\)'   -exec mv {} Compressed  \;

# #Executable
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*apk\|.*exe\|.*rpm\|.*msi\|.*pks\|.*jar\)' -exec mv {} Executable \;

# #Fonts
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '\(.*ttf\|.*otf\|.*fon\|.*fnt\)'   -exec mv {} Fonts  \;

# Delete empty directories
find . -maxdepth 1 -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```